# Can I install NFS server and run it under Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: nfs

Can install nfs-kernel-server as written in  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-nfs under Ubuntu desktop and run it "out of the box?" Thanks

Comment: NFS and NTFS are different filesystems - what is your end goal, exactly?

Comment: Yes you can use `nfs-kernel-server` on Ubuntu Desktop.  On install it won't have a setup; that has to be done by the user/operator.   You haven't provided release details so this is generic.

Comment: Oops, I miss read the original tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Works as advertised. You already know the initial steps of the setup, as the link you posted shows.

You may widen your knowledge by searching the web for "/etc/exports examples".